# Tests Target in importance

Tags: ios, xcode

Why is the test target created when we create a new X Code project and what do we use it for...?

> error: could not read data from '/Users/abc/Downloads/ExampleappusingPhotosframework/SamplePhotosAppTests/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

This error can be removed by deleting the tests target file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test target is VERY (yes, very) important to iOS projects (for any projects in that matter) which are used to write unit test cases for your project. You can find about the test targets and the samples from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-test_navigator/AddingTestBundles/AddingTestBundles.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/testing_4_running_tests/testing_4_running_tests.html).

But the problem in your case is not with the target but with the .plist file. Each target have their own .plist files and the .plist file for your test target is missing.

You can correct this error by giving the correct .plist file path to your test target. Go to the **XCode project -> Select TestScheme -> Build Settings -> Search for info.plist and give the correct file path**. Or just copy the file path from your main target settings.

[image: Build Settings]

Answer (score 0):

its not much important . You can Delete it from your Project.
if its gives error or something then delete complete from your Code.